# Cannot find Android AVD on Android Studio for Mac

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 for Mac, and it seems like AVD manager is not installed, but when I reinstalled Android studio, it showed me in custom installation that it was installed on my Mac

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.genymotion.com/ that provides good support as a Android Emulator. Its performance is better than Android Studio Emulator

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:
I completely uninstalled android studio and on custom installation installed this avd manager

On first installation I chose standard, and that's why it didn't install any avd